# Algorithm for distribution of numbers in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, optimization

This is my first question on stack exchange. I'm working on a problem where I need to find a distribution of non-negative integers in a matrix where each row and each column adds up to a target total. I am sure there is an algorithm that can do this (or a theory that says when this is possible and when it is not) but I haven't had much luck finding this online.

In the attached image ([Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yn9El.png)) I have an example of a solution that I found for a specific instance of the problem but there was no definable algorithm involved. The grey totals are the target totals for each column and row while the light blue totals are the totals for the current distribution shown. At the beginning of the algorithm only the totals are provided so I start with an empty matrix.

Could someone please point me to a resource/solution for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Integers only? (which is of course harder than distributing continuous values) Strictly positve only? You see, details are important

Comment: Hi, yes Integers only.

Comment: Positive integers (including 0). I've updated the question, thank you.

Comment: @TinusWillemse when you want to add information as answer to a comment, it is highly recommended to edit your question with the extended information.
and what do you mean by Optimal distribution?

Comment: Hi @TomerW, thank you. I've now updated my question. I realize now that "optimal" wasn't the correct word as there might be multiple solutions that satisfy the constraints. I've therefore removed "optimal" from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a hard-problem (probably **np-hard**).

Your best bet (ignoring domain-dependent highly-tuned algorithms) are the classic approaches for combinatorial-optimization:

- Metaheuristics (Tabu-search, Simulated-annealing & co.)

  - Needs some tuning / Neighborhood-definitions ...
- SAT-solvers

  - Needs annoying emulation of adders
  - **complete** (can prove, that there is no solution)
- Constraint-programming

  - Easy to formulate
  - Can be tuned
  - **complete**
- Integer-programming

  - Easy to formulate as shown below
  - Very good commercial-solvers available
  - **complete**
    I will present a simple version of the latter (which is probably the worst approach of these; at least for this problem!)

It's implemented within python and uses the open-source tools [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/) (formulation) & [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc) (MIP-solver).

#### Code

**Update:** fix some element-values a-priori!

```python
from cvxpy import *

targets_X = [17, 45, 7, 6]
targets_Y = [3 for i in range(11)] + [2 for i in range(21)]
fixed_elements_indices_x, fixed_elements_indices_y = [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]
fixed_elements_values = [3, 3, 3]
dim_x, dim_y = len(targets_X), len(targets_Y)

# Vars
T = Int(dim_x, dim_y)

# Constraints
constraints = []
constraints.append(T >= 0)
constraints.append(sum_entries(T, axis=1) == targets_X)
constraints.append(sum_entries(T, axis=0).T == targets_Y)
constraints.append(T[fixed_elements_indices_x, fixed_elements_indices_y] == fixed_elements_values)
problem = Problem(Minimize(0), constraints)
problem.solve(CBC, verbose=True)

print(T.value.T)
```

#### Output

```
Clp0006I 0  Obj 0 Primal inf 159 (39)
Clp0006I 36  Obj 0 Primal inf 98.999998 (19)
Clp0006I 69  Obj 0
Clp0006I 69  Obj 0
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 0
Cbc0045I No integer variables out of 128 objects (128 integer) have costs
Cbc0045I branch on satisfied N create fake objective Y random cost Y
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 0
Node 0 depth 0 unsatisfied 0 sum 0 obj 0 guess 0 branching on -1
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 0
Cbc0004I Integer solution of 0 found after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.00 seconds)
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective 0, took 0 iterations and 0 nodes (0.00 seconds)
Cbc0035I Maximum depth 0, 0 variables fixed on reduced cost
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 0
Clp0000I Optimal - objective value 0
[[ 3.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  3.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  3.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  3.]
 [ 0.  2.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  3.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 2.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Comment: Thank you @sascha. If the problem gets modified by saying that some of the matrix values can't be changed (are set to 0) is there a way to use the methods that you mentioned?

Comment: @TinusWillemse All the mentioned methods are very general and can easily incorporate this. In the above it's just one more line of code. **Edit:** I added it

Comment: you don't possibly know how to formulate the above solution using C# and the Google OR Tools library? I'm trying to figure this out but both integer programming and the library are new to me. I need to integrate this into a .Net application.

Comment: @TinusWillemse It should be very easy to do this with ORtools, if they provide a MIP-solver. The only thing to do is to convert my matrix-form constraints to a form their lib supports. This could be even easier if you just look at your problem (easy rules like sum == X and co.). Using Constraint-programming, the problem itself can be defined even easier but tuning might be needed. Read the docs of the lib, work trough the examples and when something is not working as expected, post a new question asking about a specific problem.

Comment: I managed to get the problem coded in ORtools. I just needed to spend the time getting to know the library as you said. Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in polynomial time using a [maximum flow algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem).

Set up a source node, a node for each row, a node for each column and a destination node.

Edges from source to a row node should have capacity equal to the given row sum.

Edges from a col node to the dest should have capacity equal to the given column sum.

Edges from a row node to a col node should have capacity according to the allowed values in your matrix.  (e.g. if an entry at row x, col y of the matrix must be zero, then set the capacity to 0 for the edge from row node x to col node y.)

Then compute the maximum flow from source to destination, and the flow between row nodes and column nodes gives the entries in your matrix.

Complexity is O(n^3) for a solution to a nxn matrix.

Comment: Should this apply to OPs desire for an integral-solution? (integers-only) I don't think so. The constraint-matrix does not look totally unimodular and even if, it does not help with the multi-commodity flow problem.

Comment: All flows will be integer because all capacities are integer.  (Consider a method that computes maximum flow by finding an augmenting flow, each augmentation will always be an integer amount so the flow will stay integral.)